Give an example of a weak contraction on a complete metric space that is not a contraction
I was given the following question: Give an example of a complete metric space $(X, d)$ and $f:X \rightarrow X$ such that $d(f(x), f(y)) < d(x, y)$ for all distinct $x, y \in X$, but f is not a contraction.
I gave the following solution: Take $([1, \infty), \mathbb{E}^1)$, and $f(x) = x + \frac{1}{x}$. We know X is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$, which is complete. Hence X is complete. Taking the derivative, we have that $f'(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{x^2}$. However, since $x$ can take any values from $[1, \infty)$, it is the case that $d(f(x), f(y)) < d(x, y)$ for all distinct $x, y \in X$. Yet, we have that $\lim_{x \rightarrow\infty}{f'(x)} = 1$. Hence, it is not a contraction. Therefore, it is not obliged to be a fixed point, which there is isn't.
Is my argument about the limit enough to show that $f$ is not a contraction? Is it correct? Any feedback is appreciated!

Many of these Mathematics SE questions are relevant.

Every contraction has a unique fixed point. But $f(x)$ has no fixed point since $f(x)=x$ would imply $$x+\frac1x=x$$ which is evidently impossible. It can therefore not be a contraction.
